# Spring JPA query not get parameters

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

Hi I'm using spring with JPA and Crud Repository but I have a problem using findById(), When I use findAll I'm not having trouble and fetch all data in my DB.

But using FindById() the query is printed as following (Also I tried with nativeQuery but I got same result):

`SELECT * from TABLE_USERS where ID_USR_PK = ?`

Entity code:

```
Entity:
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_USERS ", schema = "khrisna")
public class Usuario {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_USR_PK", nullable = false)
    String userId;
    
    @Column(name="DET_USER")
    String detail;
```

CrudRepository Interface whit QueryNative Test:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM TABLE_USERS WHERE ID_USR_PK = ?" ,nativeQuery = true)
Usuario findByUserId(@Param(value="userId")String userId);
```

Any idea could you help me to solve it?

Comment: This is an expected behavior. As per your code, you are trying to retrieve a row based on the ID. If you can tell what you are trying to achieve  or what is your objective, then may be I can help you

Comment: Thanks, yes I try to get the row that match with ID given in RequestParam controller

Comment: So where is the problem? What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what does happen?

Comment: @JensSchauder problem is I'm not retrieving any data

Comment: Log the bind parameters of the SQL statement as well. Do they have the values you expect? How did the data get in the database? Is it there from a previous transaction? You are using positional parameters in the query but use `@Param` to name the argument. Remove the annotation or use named parameters in the query and check if that helps.

Comment: @JensSchauder I bind the parameter and I get this : descriptor.sql.BasicBinder     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [os456]